# How to match regex with conditions?

Tags: javascript, regex

**"Fingerprint (rear-mounted, region dependent), accelerometer, proximity"**

Above is the string of **sensors** in a device. I'm trying to match every sensor. The problem is that when I match above using `/.+?,/g`, The matches are:

1. Fingerprint (rear-mounted,
2. region dependent),
3. accelerometer,
4. proximity

I'm getting 4 sensors here instead of three. Because, of course, my pattern matches these. What I want to do is that when a `,` is preceded by `(`, then I want to match `),` and when not preceded by `(`, I want to match `,`

I think I need to use lookarounds here. But I can't get them to work for me. I tried multiple regexes. It's silly to paste them all here :)

*I'm using JavaScript*

Comment: What do you eventually want as a result?

Comment: _I'm getting 4 sensors here instead of **three**_. I want three sensors.

Comment: But which values exactly do you want? Can you update the question with the desired result?

Comment: Yes, I know you've selected an answer already, but I'm curious, too: what would you want for your result? I'm guessing *Fingerprint*, *accelerometer*, *proximity*, and *compass* - but then you said you only wanted 3?

Comment: My bad. I pasted the wrong string. It was actually **Fingerprint (rear-mounted, region dependent), accelerometer, proximity**. I apologise

Answer (score 1):

Here is one way to do so:

```
(?:[^(,]+(?:\([^)]*\))?)+?(?:, |$)
```

See the online demo [here](https://regex101.com/r/HYWyOG/1).

```js
const pattern = /(?:[^(,]+(?:\([^)]*\))?)+?(?:, |$)/g;
const str = 'Fingerprint (rear-mounted, region dependent), accelerometer, proximity';

const matches = str.matchAll(pattern)
for (const match of matches) {
  console.log(match[0]);
}
```

---

- `(?:)+?`: Non capturing group, repeated between one and unlimited times, as few as possible.

  - `[^(,]`: Matches any character other than `(` or `,`.
  - `(?:)?`: Optional non capturing group.

    - `\(`: Matches `(`.
    - `[^)]*`: Matches any character other than `)`, between zero and unlimited times, as much as possible.
    - `\)`: Matches `)`.
- `(?:)`: Non capturing group.

  - `,` : Matches `,` .
  - `|`: Or.
  - `$`: Matches the end of the string.